# Using PL/SQL Function returning query to populate LOV

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to populate a LOV using a PL/SQL Function returning a Query for the first time. I can't seem to get the syntax correct as I'm always receiving the following error on validation:

> ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 145: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

of the following PL/SQL Function:

```
DECLARE
EMPLOYEES NUMBER := 0;
QR varchar(4000);

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO EMPLOYEES FROM TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT
WHERE MAN_QT = :APP_USER

IF EMPLOYEES = 0 THEN

QR :=     'select FIRST_NAME|| '' '' ||LAST_NAME d, select FIRST_NAME|| '' '' 
    ||LAST_NAME r 
     FROM TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT 
     WHERE MAN_QT IN (SELECT QT FROM TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT
            WHERE MAN_QT = (SELECT MAN_QT FROM TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT 
                      WHERE QT = :APP_USER)) AND FL = ''ESA''';

ELSE

QR :=     'select FIRST_NAME|| '' '' ||LAST_NAME d, select FIRST_NAME|| '' '' 
    ||LAST_NAME r 
    from TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT 
    where MAN_QT = :APP_USER';
END IF;

RETURN QR;
END
```

This is confusing as Line 2 is part of my declaration area and I wouldn't expect a FROM here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, queries use wrong syntax. You can't have two `SELECT`s, e.g.

```
select FIRST_NAME|| '' '' ||LAST_NAME d, select FIRST_NAME||
------                                   ------
here                                     here
```

Should have been

```
select FIRST_NAME|| ' ' ||LAST_NAME d, FIRST_NAME||
```

As you noticed (if you did, that is), I substituted two consecutive single quotes with one. Of course, it'll fail because you're writing dynamic SQL and have to "escape" single quotes. But, I'd suggest you to use the q-quoting mechanism which is easier to write and maintain. Something like this:

```
QR := q'[select FIRST_NAME|| ' ' || LAST_NAME d, 
                FIRST_NAME|| ' ' || LAST_NAME r 
         FROM TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT 
         WHERE MAN_QT IN (SELECT QT FROM TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT
                          WHERE MAN_QT = (SELECT MAN_QT FROM TS4_USER@TS_INFO_4.STT 
                                          WHERE QT = :APP_USER
                                         )
                         ) 
           AND FL = 'ESA']';
```

Though, aren't you overcomplicating it? Isn't it just

```
select ...
from ts4_user
where qt = :APP_USER
  and fl = 'ESA'
```

Also, select lists have two values: `display` and `return` ones. We *usually* display names and return IDs; you're having "names" in both cases. I'm not saying that it is wrong, it's just somewhat unusual.

---

Therefore: **first** make sure that query you write returns desired value in SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer or whichever tool you use), **then** move it to Apex.

---

P.S. Don't be sorry for formatting. Put some effort in it and make your (and our) life simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the response Littlefoot!  It looks like the double select and another small issue took care of it.  

It was an odd problem I had to account for within our management structure.  The else is for managers who have people directly reporting to them.  The original IF part is for "Ops Leads" that don't have anyone directly assigned to them, but have responsibilities that include those under the managers.  So, I basically had to go up a level, then down two to find out who that person would be responsible and develop a LOV based on that.  

Yay middle management.